# How to pass file path in yaml file

Tags: jenkins, yaml

I am writing cucumber js bdd script for api automation.
I have folder of project in github repository. In that folder, I have many file and folders.
1 of them file is jobconfig.yaml file.
I am using Jenkins to run these. But in output console,  i can only see jobconfig.yaml is running. Other files are not running.
So I wanted to ask, if there is any way to give path of file in yaml file,  so that it can also run.

Please help, I am really tensed for many days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to run files that live in your github repo, I believe you can utilize some of YAML's [predefine variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to suit your needs. In particular, `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` returns the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. This would be the top-level folder of your github repo. So, for example, you could reference a file in your repo like such:
`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FolderName\FileName.*extension*`

If you are just trying to reference other YAML templates from your YAML file, then the paths are relative to the current YAML file.

Comment: Hi Logan, thank you very much for your reply. And yes, I want to run file that is present in my github repository.  Basically I have Jenkinsfile file in my github repository. And i want to run that file. In jenkins, only my yaml file is running. So I was thinking i will set path of Jenkinsfile in that yaml file.